# Two way passing data

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-decorator

I have 2 components: AppComponent and ChildComponent.
ChildComponent is the child component of AppComponent.
How to to send altered "variable1" from ChildComponent back to AppComponent?

AppComponent [html]:

```
<child [variable1]="variable1">PARENT</child>
```

AppComponent [ts]:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  variable1: string = 'abc';
}
```

ChildComponent [ts]:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input('variable1') variable1: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.variable1 = this.variable1 + 'def';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an `EventEmitter` and `@Output` and marking two-way-binding in your child tag. So your child tag add two-way-binding:

```
<child [(variable1)]="variable1">PARENT</child>
```

in your child mark this event emitter with the variable name, and suffix `Change` (important for two-way-binding to work!)

```
@Input() variable1: string;
@Output() variable1Change = new EventEmitter<string>()
```

and whenever you want to pass the variable change to parent, in child do:

```
this.variable1Change.emit('my new value')
```

*As a sidenote, notice I removed the alias from your `@Input`, this based on the docs style guide: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#avoid-aliasing-inputs-and-outputs*

Answer (score 0):

I might come a bit late, but there's even easier : use viewChildren :

parent component TS :

```
@ViewChild('child') child: ChildComponent;
// ...
this.myVariable = this.child.variable1;
```

parent component HTML :

```
<child #child>PARENT</child>
```

child component TS :

```
variable1 = '';
// ... 
this.variable1 = 'Hello world';
```

Answer (score 0):

Below example has both parent to child interaction and child to parent interaction. [you can also try here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-interaction)

app.component.ts - Parent component

```
import { Component, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  //passing values from parent to child
  master = "child";

  //Getting value from child
  childToParent(name){
    this.master=name;
  }

}
```

app.component.html - HTML of Parent component

```
<div>
  <span>Master to Child </span><input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]='master'>
</div>

<app-child [master]=master (childToParent)="childToParent($event)"></app-child>
```

app-child.component.ts - child component

```
import { Component, Input, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]='masterName'>
    <button (click)="sendToParent(masterName)" >sendToParent</button>
  `
})
export class AppChildComponent {
  //getting value from parent to child
  @Input('master') masterName: string;

  @Output() childToParent = new EventEmitter<String>();

  sendToParent(name){
    this.childToParent.emit(name);
  }
}
```